# How to Bring layout back to its original position in android after drag

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have working on a project. where I need to drag the layout,  I manage to move (drag) the layout but when I release the touch it is not coming at its original position.

Please anyone tell me what should I do in MotionEvent.ACTION_UP so that I can get layout back to its original position.

Following is my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    RelativeLayout _view;
    RelativeLayout _view1;
    // TextView _view;
    ViewGroup _root;
    private int _xDelta;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mainlParams;
    private int _yDelta;

    // private int X1, Y1, width;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        _root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);

        _view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);



        _view.setOnTouchListener(this);
        lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) _view.getLayoutParams();
        mainlParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) _view.getLayoutParams();
        // _root.addView(_view1);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
        lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.e("", "inside ACTION_DOWN");
            lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.e("", "inside ACTION_UP");
            if ((X - _xDelta) < -150) {
                _root.removeView(_view);
            } else {
                view.setLayoutParams(mainlParams);
            }

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.e("", "inside ACTION_MOVE");

            layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;

            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
        }
        _root.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

### NEW EDIT

here I show you a very simple (and by the way not very clean code) how to do what you want to do. I have a relativeLayout with a green LinearLayout inside:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/moving_layout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then in Your MainActivity, set the topLayout, where the view You want to move is inside, to onTouchListener. Set originalX and originalY at ACTION_DOWN and moveX and moveY at ACTION_MOVE. When user release fingers, go back to original position:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
private float originalX = 0;
private float originalY = 0;
private float moveX = 0;
private float moveY = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.moving_layout);
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    mRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    int width = getMetrics(100);
    int height = getMetrics(100);

    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

}



/**
 * converts dp to px
 * 
 * @param dp
 * @return
 */
private int getMetrics(int dp) {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) ((dp * displayMetrics.density) + 0.5);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):

        originalX = event.getX(); //set X start position
        originalY = event.getY();//set Y start position
        moveX = event.getX();//first move x
        moveY = event.getY();//first move y
        break;

    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):

        moveX = event.getX();//set move x
        moveY = event.getY();//set move y

        //set LayoutParams to mLinearLayout
        params.leftMargin = (int) moveX;
        params.topMargin = (int) moveY;
        mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        break;

    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):

        //set mLinearLayout back to original position
        params.leftMargin = (int) originalX;
        params.topMargin = (int) originalY;
        mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        break;

    }
    return true;
}

    }
```

Don´t wonder about the getMetrics() Method, this is because setting same width and height to mLinearLayout like defined in xml. In xml, you set this values as dp, at LayoutParams, it is px. But this is not relevant for Your question. 
What I am doin here is, set original X and Y at ACTION_DOWN and get back to this at ACTION_UP. So, everytime the user press down again, these values will be "renewed", the layout will going back to the last points of ACTION_DOWN if fingers will release. This should give You an idea how to handle your problem.

Comment: how to assign these val to layout.

Comment: Yes, I want to do same thing. But My layout is not coming to original position.

Comment: whats gonna happen? is your view disappearing or does it stay at the last position where finger touches?

Comment: It changes its position slightly towards right but not to the original.

Comment: ok, sorry, I can´t imagine what You are trying for now, I can´t do some programming at the moment. But if You want to only move Your linear layout, you could try to set layoutParams.x and layoutParams.y position. I edited my answer...I think I will give it a try when i am at home, so I could tell You the right way later, if this is not what You want